# Plotly R- Can not adjust orientation of colorbar

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, scatter

I am trying to create a scatterplot within a Shiny App that has a colorbar with a horizontal orientation. Based on my reading of the [Plotly reference](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/coloraxis/#layout-coloraxis-colorbar-orientation) it appears that the orientation of a colorbar can be adjusted within Layout/Coloraxis/Colorbar by setting orientation="h".

After many attempts and tweaks I can not find a way to get the colorbar to be displayed horizontally.

Any help would be appreciated.

Minimal example using the iris dataset:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
          plotlyOutput("Scatter")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

      ScatterPlot<-reactive({
        plot_ly(
                iris,
                type='scatter',
                mode='lines+markers'
            )%>%
            add_trace(
                x=~Sepal.Length, 
                y=~Sepal.Width,
                mode='markers',
                marker=list(
                  color=~Petal.Length,
                  coloraxis='coloraxis'
                        )
                )%>%
            layout(
                showlegend=FALSE,
                margin=list(b=50),
                coloraxis=list(
                 colorbar=list(
                   orientation="h"
                   )
                  )
                )
                   }
        )
      
      output$Scatter<-renderPlotly({ScatterPlot()})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2147).

Comment: Thank you for filing the issue. I will track it there to see if there is any resolution. Really appreciate your help!